# Como podría validar si una string finaliza con un punto, o con un punto seguido de espacios o si es una cadena vacía?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```py
import re

def aaa(i):
    if(i == 0): a = ''
    elif(i == 1): a = 'Hola, como estás?.  '
    elif(i == 2): a = 'Yo estube programando algo'
    elif(i == 3): a = 'no esta mal ese celular, lo uso en la oficina.'

    return a

text, i_text = "", ""

for i in range(4):
    print(i)
    i_text = aaa(i)
    #AQUI DEBERIA ESTAR LA REGEX O LINEA VERIFICADORA DE LA PUNTUACION
    text = text + i_text + ". "

print(repr(text))  # --> output
```

Como debería hacer para agregar los puntos solamente cuando la string recibida de la función de ejemplo `aaa()` no sea una string que finalice con un punto `.` , o que sea una string que tan solo tenga espacios en blanco o que directamente no tenga nada (como es el caso de la primera de ellas).

En tal caso, en lugar de obtener este output con las puntuaciones hechas incorrectamente

```
'. Hola, como estás?.  . Yo estube programando algo. no esta mal ese celular, lo uso en la oficina.. '
```

El output correcto debería ser:

```
'Hola, como estás?. Yo estube programando algo. no esta mal ese celular, lo uso en la oficina.'
```

Es muy importante que el control de los puntos al final de cada `i_text` se haga en cada iteración, y no al final de todo previo a usar el `print()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `agregar(frase)` recibe una frase y agrega un punto al final sólo si contiene un texto (no vacío) que **no** termina en punto.

```
def agregar(frase):
    texto = frase.rstrip()
    return frase if not texto or texto.endswith('.') else texto + '.'
```

La función primero elimina los espacios al final para poder analizar el último caracter efectivo del texto.

Si el texto termina en '.' (o es un texto vacio), se devuelve el texto con un punto agregado al final.

Usamos el 'if' en formato 'en-linea', que es equivalente a:

```
if not texto or texto.endswith('.') :
   return frase
else:
   return texto + '.'
```

#### Demo

```
def agregar(frase):
    texto = frase.rstrip()
    return frase if not texto or texto.endswith('.') else texto + '.'

tests = ['',
         'Hola, como estás?.  ',
         'Yo estuve programando algo',
         'no está mal ese celular, lo uso en la oficina.']

for test in tests:
    print(test, " -> ", agregar(test))
```

produce:

```
  ->  
Hola, como estás?.    ->  Hola, como estás?.  
Yo estuve programando algo  ->  Yo estuve programando algo.
no está mal ese celular, lo uso en la oficina.  ->  no está mal ese celular, lo uso en la oficina.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def aaa(i):
    if( i == 0 ): a = ''
    elif( i == 1 ): a = 'Hola, como estás?.  '
    elif( i == 2 ): a = 'Yo estube programando algo'
    elif( i == 3 ): a = 'no esta mal ese celular, lo uso en la oficina.'
    return a

aux = ""
i_text = ""

for i in range(4):
    aux = aaa(i)
    if( aux != "" ): 
        pos = text.find( "." ) +1
        if( pos == 0 ):
            i_text += aux + ". "
        else:
            i_text += aux[ 0 : pos ] + " "
        
print( i_text )  # --> output
```

La función es muy sencilla, con el primer **if**, descarta las cadenas vacias.
Si la cadena no esta vacia, en el otro **if**, pedimos con **find(".")**, la posición del primer punto y le sumamos **1**.
con el siguiente **if**, verificamos que **pos**, sea igual a cero (osea, **find** devolvió **-1** porque no encontró un punto), si es así, cargamos en **i_text**, la cadena recibida mas un punto y un espacio.
En el **else**, cortamos la cadena recibida desde **0** hasta **pos**, y le agregamos un espacio, para luego cargarla en **i_text**.
Espero que te sea de utilidad.